# tempfile syntax in python 2.4.3

Tags: python, with-statement, python-2.4

I have the following code which runs perfectly on Python 2.6.6:

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as scriptfile:
        scriptfile.write(<variablename>)
        scriptfile.flush()
        subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', scriptfile.name])
```

However, when I try to run it on Python 2.4.3, I get the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as scriptfile
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a change in syntax in Python 2.4.3?

Comment: `with` statement can be used in py2.5+ only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2.4 does not support the `with` statement. So you just need to open and close the `scriptfile` manually.

```
scriptfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

# whatever you need to do with `scriptfile`

scriptfile.close()
```

Comment: could you include the syntax as well please?

Comment: A `try:`, `finally:` would be helpful here to match the `with` behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

[The `with`-statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) is available only since Python 2.5 using `from __future__ import with_statement` and it is enabled by default since Python 2.6.

To emulate its behaviour, you could use `try/finally`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.4
import subprocess
import tempfile

scriptfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
try:
    scriptfile.write(<variablename>)
    scriptfile.flush()
    subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', scriptfile.name])
finally:
    scriptfile.close()
```

btw, you could avoid creating a file on disk by passing the script via a pipe:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('/bin/bash', stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(<variablename>)
```

There are some differences but it might work as is in your case.