# Invalid syntax when opening .csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, import, python-2.x

The error message:

```
File "./reading_and_creating_outage_report.py", line 6
with open('major_outages_csv.csv',mode='w') as csv_file:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm stumped. Every example I've seen on Stack Overflow and elsewhere uses this syntax to open a csv file residing in the same directroy as the script. I have found other methods, but I don't like not knowing what is wrong with the way I'm writing this considering it seems to be the same all other samples.

referenced material:

https://realpython.com/python-csv/

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

script in question:

```
import csv
with open('major_outages_csv.csv',mode='w') as csv_file:
    csv_reader  = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
            if line_count == 0:
                    print('column headers are {", ".join(row)}')
                    line_count += 1
            else:
                    print('\t{row[0]} is the number of customers out and {row[1]} is the feeder.')
                    line_count += 1
    print ('processed {line_count} lines.')
```

Comment: Your indentation is out in places.  That will produce errors.  Keep indentations to 4 spaces only

Comment: Please make sure to include the complete code. Your traceback mentions line 6, but in your sample it would be line 2

Comment: I tried the code you posted and there is no SyntaxError. My only suggestion is that you are using very old version of Python below 2.5 that doesn't support `with` statement

Comment: it's true. I excluded commented lines.

Comment: The version must be the problem. My version is 2.4.3 (it cannot be updated). I think this thread may provide the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651456/tempfile-syntax-in-python-2-4-3

Comment: You can find the docs for 2.4.3 [here](https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The issue was the version of python. As mentioned in many other posts on StackExchange, python versions older than 2.5 do not support `with` statements.

If one wishes to read a .csv file using a version of python older than 2.5, the below script works.

```
import csv
csv_reader = csv.reader(open("file_name.csv","rb"),delimiter=',')
for fields in csv_reader:
     print fields
```